# Kafka replicator setup architecture

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two Kafka clusters, one in London and another in NYC. Each has three Zookeeper instances and two brokers. There are two topics used in each region a InputData topic and an OutputData topic. I want each region to replicate the data from the other one, ie for them to effectively be using a global Inputdata and OutputData topic. If NYC adds two messages to this, it should be replicated to EMEA. If EMEA adds three messages, those should go to NYC.

My question is how do I achieve this? Does two way replication work or do you get into an endless loop/are there issues with concurrency. Ie what happens if NYC writes the messages locally at the same time EMEA writes its messages, then replicator tries to get the topics synched but they are now out of sync.

Is this even possible? Or can replication only work one way - ie you have to have a source topic that is only written from the main cluster, and the places it is replicated to are read only?

My second question is how do I make the replicator fault tolerant, do I run it in distributed mode with one connect worker per server - which in this case would make it two connect workers per cluster?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_mirror_maker

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Confluent Replicator? Or in general about replication between Kafka clusters?